# Korean more efficient keyboard?

Tags: typing

Is there an equivalent to Dvorak for Korean?

I think it is interesting that I find no frequency maps on Google for the Korean alphabet at least in English that is.

[image]

Comment: Korean keyboards separate consonants (on the left) and vowels (on the right). So it is already much more efficients than a QWERTY. I don't know if the consonants and the vowels parts have been optimized like Dvorak though.

Comment: @Taladris although I agree it looks more efficient the qwerty first glance you have to keep in mind when you press shift the most efficient thing would be to be to put the additional keys on the home row but they don't so I don't think it was completely thought through.

Comment: In addition there is the problem that qwerty/english doesn't combine to make different characters like Korean does.  It appears they did the most logical thing for someone to find keys on the keyboard especially for the shift keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Korean people almost 99% they use 2-set Korean, it is equivalent to qwert type keyboard. Dvorak is not directly equivalent to 3-set Keyboard but it design for efficiency. However it takes time to get use to it, also it require extra step to setup most of time.

I believe most Korean people use 2-set with qwert keyboard. For fast typing they use specialized keyboard at the court.

속기자판 https://www.google.com/search?q=%EC%86%8D%EA%B8%B0%EC%9E%90%ED%8C%90&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUi73JpLLRAhVlzIMKHY4TB9AQ_AUICCgB&biw=1858&bih=990

ref) http://moogi.new21.org/ngstype/faq8.htm

Comment: so it does appear that someone else believes the same thing as you https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-all-the-Korean-keyboard-layouts-that-OS-X-offers-me-2-set-3-set-390-sebulshik-and-which-is-the-best-default-one

Comment: 2nd links How to use Dvorak in Korean :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure you've seen that there numerous, Korean key layouts available.  I only know "2-Set Korean".  I would have only left a comment, but then I couldn't drop in this screenshot.  All the Korean typing programs that I've seen use 2-Set Korean.  But then again, I've never seen a Dvorak typing tutor (without argument, that is, perhaps because I haven't searched for one).

[image]

Comment: Since I can't read korean I can't tell which is best which is unfortunate found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Hangul_.28for_Korean.29  Also you can just post a link to the image once uploaded to post as comment..